# Add fractional component in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column with values like the following:

1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
etc

I would like to change the values to

1.0 1.25 1.5 1.75 2.0 2.25 2.5 2.75 3.0 3.25 3.5 3.75 etc

The initial integer values are always monotonically increasing, but may have gaps. They will always be repeated exactly 4 times.

I have implemented this via a for loop, but this takes a long time to run on a large data set. I'm looking for a more efficient way.

```
for i in range(len(df) // 4):
    for j in range(4):
        df.timestamp.iloc[i * 4 + j] += j / samples_per_sec
```

Comment: What do you mean 'may have gaps'.  Can you please provide a sample of this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
In [47]:
l=[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 ,3 ,3 ,3, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':l})
df['values'] = df['values'] + (0.25 * (df.index.values % 4 ))
df

Out[47]:
    values
0     1.00
1     1.25
2     1.50
3     1.75
4     2.00
5     2.25
6     2.50
7     2.75
8     3.00
9     3.25
10    3.50
11    3.75
```

So assuming that any values that are present are always repeated 4 times, as you've stated then the above should work.

using another dataset with gaps:

```
In [48]:
l=[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2 ,4 ,4 ,4, 4,7,7,7,7]
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':l})
df['values'] = df['values'] + (0.25 * (df.index.values % 4 ))
df

Out[48]:
    values
0     1.00
1     1.25
2     1.50
3     1.75
4     2.00
5     2.25
6     2.50
7     2.75
8     4.00
9     4.25
10    4.50
11    4.75
12    7.00
13    7.25
14    7.50
15    7.75
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
df.timestamp += [(j % samples_per_sec)*1. / samples_per_sec for j in range(len(df))]
```

Note: I'm assuming that `samples_per_sec = 4`.